# Minicom no cmd on start up

Tags: connection, serial-port, router

I am using minicom in cents to try to connect to a cisco router. I did the configuration with `minicom -s` changed the serial port to the appropriate one `/dev/ttyS1`. Saved as dfl. and Exit.

When minicom started i got the following.

```
Welcome to minicom 2.3
Options: 118n
Compiled on Nov 23 2010, 13:27:13
Port /dev/ttyS1

press CTRL-A z for help on special keys
```

I don't see the `cmd:` line though. Do i need to set up anything else?

Answer (score 4):

At first check the router manual for baud rate. Then access minicom like this (here baud rate is 9600)-

```
$sudo minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyS1
```

Now press **CTRL+A** and then **Z**, and then **O**, and select **serial port setup**. Press **F** to make the **Hardware Flow Control** to **NO**.

Now save it, and Exit. You should see the `cmd:` line now. If no luck, access minicom again as I described above, check the **Hardware Flow Control** is **NO**. Wait for some time in `press CTRL-A z for help on special keys` screen. Press **Enter** key in the keyboard and wait again. If no luck, then switch off the router only, wait for some time and switch on the router again, while you are waiting on the minicom screen. I think now you could see some output from the router in your minicom.